# Why isn't my series name showing up in my Line chart default legend in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, interop

I'm trying to do something that should be straightforward.  I want the legend in my Excel line chart to have custom names.  I'm creating the chart in C# (interop).  What I have so fare is:

```
Excel.Range xvalues = myWorkSheet.Range["R3", "R5"];
Excel.Range values1 = myWorkSheet.Range["S3", "S5"];
Excel.Range values2 = myWorkSheet.Range["T3", "T5"];
Excel.Range values3 = myWorkSheet.Range["U3", "U5"];
Excel.Range values4 = myWorkSheet.Range["V3", "V5"];

Excel.SeriesCollection sc = myChart.SeriesCollection();
myChart.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;

Excel.Series series1 = sc.NewSeries();
Excel.Series series2 = sc.NewSeries();
Excel.Series series3 = sc.NewSeries();
Excel.Series series4 = sc.NewSeries();

series1.XValues = xValues;
series1.Values = values1;
series1.Name = "mySeries1";

series2.XValues = xValues;
series2.Values = values2;
series2.Name = "mySeries2";    

series3.XValues = xValues;
series3.Values = values3;
series3.Name = "mySeries3";

series4.XValues = xValues;
series4.Values = values4;
series4.Name = "mySeries4";
```

The chart displays fine, and a legend appears where I want it, but the series names don't appear with the line colors in the legend.  Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

What I didn't put in the code, was the fact that I position the legend within the chart area.  I had set the myChart.Legend.Height, myChart.Legend.Left and myChart.Legend.Top properties.  I figured that I didn't need to set the Legend.Width property, as I thought that the legend would automatically set that to the proper width.  I was wrong.  Once I set the myChart.Legend.Width property, then the series names showed up.